# NavigationView Item with extra content on right side

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a `NavigationView` in my app. I want to add counters/badges to some of the items. But whatever I do, the badge always stays right next to the label. See the image below (on the top is what I have, on the bottom what I want to achieve)

[image]

The code I'm currently using is the following:

```xml
<NavigationViewItem Icon="Mail">
    <NavigationViewItem.Content>
        <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True">Inbox</TextBlock>
            <local:Badge RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" BadgeText="30"/> <!-- can be replaced with a simple "TextBlock" -->
        </RelativePanel>
    </NavigationViewItem.Content>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

<sup>(You can subsitute the `Badge` control with a simple `TextBlock`)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `RelativePanel` can't get `SplitViewOpenPaneThemeLength` automatically. so we need specific the width for  `RelativePanel`. As we known `SplitViewOpenPaneThemeLength` is **320**, and `SplitViewCompactPaneThemeLength` is **48**. so the 
 width of `NavigationViewItem.Content` is **320-48 = 272**. Please refer the following xaml code.

```
<RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{ThemeResource SplitViewOpenPaneThemeLength}">
    <TextBlock RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True">Inbox</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Text="30" Margin="0,0,48,0"/>
    <!-- can be replaced with a simple "TextBlock" -->
</RelativePanel>
```

[image]